# Creating Arrays From Unknown Number of External Lists

Tags: arrays, bash, sed

this is another question related to importing values from a text file (similar to one of my previous ones), but with added complexity (the more I learn about bash scripting the more challenging it becomes)

The goal: to create an array of Day_.... on each outer loop iteration. I'm trying to do this assuming no knowledge of how many Day_... lists exist in the *.txt file.

The issue: At the moment my inner loop only iterates once (should iterate as the number of elements on `Monday`. And, also, I'm using `my_sub_dom=$( sed 's/=.*//' weekly.txt )` to get the number of lists/arrays in weekly.txt and then filter the ones that contain `Day`.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source weekly.txt

declare -a my_sub_dom
day=( ${Monday[*]} )
my_sub_dom=$( sed 's/=.*//' weekly.txt ) # to construct a list of the number of of  lists in the text file
#echo "${my_sub_dom}"
counter=0
main_counter=0
for i in "${day[@]}"
do
    let main_counter=main_counter+1
    for j in "${my_sub_dom[@]}"
    do
    #       echo "$j"
            if grep -q "Day" "${my_sub_dom}"
            then
                    echo "$j"
                    sub_array_name="${my_sub_dom[counter]}" # storing the list name
                    sub_array_content=( ${sub_array_name[*]} )
                    echo "${sub_array_content}"
            else
                    echo "no"
            fi
            let counter=counter+1
    done
    echo "$counter"
    counter=0
```

done
echo "$main_counter"

Text file format:

```
Day_Mon=( "google" "yahoo" "amazon" )
Day_Tu=( "cnn" "msnbc" "google" )
Day_Wed=( "nytimes" "fidelity" "stackoverflow" )
Monday= ( "one" "two" "three" )
....
```

Script output:

```
grep: Day_Mon
Day_Tu
Day_Wed
Monday: No such file or directory
no
1
grep: Day_Mon
Day_Tu
Day_Wed
Monday: No such file or directory
no
1
grep: Day_Mon
Day_Tu
Day_Wed
Monday: No such file or directory
no
1
3
```

Please let me know if you'd like any other information.... And I really appreciate any input in this matter, I've been trying this for a couple of days now.

Thank you

Comment: `for i in "${day[@]}"` - note missing $

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your goal. Which variables do you want to be set to what when the script is done?

Comment: @suspectus thank you, that fixed my outer loop, I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for reading the post. I'm trying to build an array from Day_Mon list and cycle through it, for example. And the output will be `Day_Mon .. google .. yahoo .. amazon ..` (each in new line). Now, to add, I like to do it to all lists that contain the string `Day` in the .txt file w/o knowing how many list names contain the string `Day` beforehand. I hope that clarifies a bit....

Answer (score 0):

Given a file `weekly.txt` containing

```
Day_Mon=( "google" "yahoo" "amazon" )
Day_Tu=( "cnn" "msnbc" "google" )
Day_Wed=( "nytimes" "fidelity" "stackoverflow" )
Monday=( "one" "two" "three" )
```

You can loop through each array named `Day_`-something with

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set all arrays defined in the file
source weekly.txt

# Get all variables prefixed with "Day_" (bash 4)
for name in "${!Day_@}"
do
  echo "The contents of array $name is: "
  # Use indirection to expand the array
  arrayexpansion="$name[@]"
  for value in "${!arrayexpansion}"
  do
    echo "-- $value"
  done
  echo
done
```

This results in:

```
The contents of array Day_Mon is:
-- google
-- yahoo
-- amazon

The contents of array Day_Tu is:
-- cnn
-- msnbc
-- google

The contents of array Day_Wed is:
-- nytimes
-- fidelity
-- stackoverflow
```